# How to set padding/margin top to footer in css3

Tags: css

I can not view my content when I scroll because sticky footer is hiding the content. I want to set footer always with margin top or padding top to able to see the content. How to set margin top or padding top to sticky footer? If i add stickyfooter I need some space between content and stickyfooter.

http://jsfiddle.net/a6c8rf4y/1/

```
#footer
{       
bottom:0px;
width:100%;
height:50px;
position:fixed;    
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
background-color: #C97;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding

```
.content {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

to your CSS your content leaves enough space at the bottom for your sticky footer to fit in when the user scrolls all the way down.

Comment: after i removed footer part space is there,,no need space after i removed footer section

Comment: is footer part removed with jquery or js

Comment: Manually...I want In all condition footer part with margin-top 50 px; In this condition only i can see all the content with footer or without footer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set new `div` with `class` `"gap-bottom"` and set it in the bottom before `<div class="content"></div>` complete.

Here is working example.

```css
*
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}
body
{
    background-color: #bbb;
}
#wrapper
{
    min-height: 99%;
    height: inherit;
    width: 950px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#header
{
    background-color: #C97;
    line-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lucida Console";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}
#main-section
{
    background-color: #ddd;
    bottom: 50px;
    top:47px;
    width:100%;
}
#footer
{       
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position:fixed;  // this is the key
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: #C97;
}
#footer_inner{
    text-align:center;
}
.gap-bottom{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="header">
        header...
    </div> <!-- end of header -->

    <div id="main-section">
      <div class="content">
                <div class="gap"></div>
                <p>First line...............</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>586 Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>893 Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>568 Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>123 Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>123 Long content goes here...</p>
                <p>Last line................</p>
                <div class="gap gap-bottom"></div>
            </div>
    </div> <!-- end of main section -->

</div> <!-- end of wrapper -->

<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_inner">footer...</div>
</div> <!-- end of footer -->
```